# Powershell script not executing correctly in SQL Server job

Tags: sql-server, excel, powershell, import-from-excel

This question has probably been asked in different ways, but I can't find anything that matches.

I have a SQL Server job that runs 2 powershell scripts.  The first one runs fine (simple IP stack query) and the 2nd one doesn't work. The 1st step in the job was to verify that my user id that I am executing the job under has the right credentialing as the SQL Agent would not work.  I am running the 2nd step as a CmdExe type to force SQL Server to execute the external updated PowerShell executable which has the Import-Excel package installed instead of the internal instance.

The complete job output is:

```
Windows IP Configuration

Ethernet adapter Ethernet0:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :  ddd
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . :  xxx
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . :  yyy
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . :  zzz
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :  aaa

========================
 Excel access error occured: 
at <ScriptBlock>, E:\tmp\tstScripts\tst_load.ps1: line 10
Data is NOT valid.
Exiting script with level  999
```

When the second task is run from PowerShell ISE or a native Powershell Window:

```
PS C:\Users\MyUserId> E:\tmp\tstScripts\tst_load.ps1
========================
The Excel sheet being worked on is MyExcel_Tst
========================
 First cell contains:  test.data.site
 Second cell contains:  97.89%
 Valid data is present.
Exiting script with level  0
```

The code that is being executed is as follows with the line in error indicated:

```
$XL_FilePath = 'C:\tmp\tstdata\';

$XL_SQL_Input = 'MyExcel_Tst';

$wSep = "========================";

try{
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application;    <<<<<----  This is error line 

$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($XL_FilePath + $XL_SQL_Input +'.xlsx');

$WorkSheet = $Workbook.Sheets.Item(2);

for ($i=1; $i -lt 3; $i++)
    { 
        $col = 1;
        $row = $i;
        if ($i -lt 2)
        { 
            $FCell = $WorkSheet.cells.Item($col, $row).Text;
        }else{
            $SCell = $WorkSheet.Cells.Item($col, $row).Text;
        }

    }

Write-Host $wSep;

Write-Host "The Excel sheet being worked on is" $WorkSheet.Name;

Write-Host $wSep;
write-host " First cell contains: " $FCell;
write-host " Second cell contains: " $SCell;

}
catch{

    Write-Host $wSep;
    Write-Host " Excel access error occured: ";
    Write-Host $_.ScriptStackTrace;
}


##  validation check - only check the 2nd value as it must be numeric, 1st is any character.

if ($SCell.Length-1 -match "^\d+$")
    {
        Write-Host " Valid data is present." -ForegroundColor Green; 
        $errorlevel = 0;
    }else{
        Write-Host "Data is NOT valid." -BackgroundColor RED -ForegroundColor Yellow;
        $errorlevel = 999;
    }


Write-Host "Exiting script with level " $errorlevel;

exit $errorlevel;
```

I know this may be a pretty simple resolution, and have wrestled with credentialing to verify that the user running the script has access and the ability to execute PowerShell scripts from the SQL Server environment.

The primary reason for this job is to validate input data before input into a database via an automated process, but the inputs are multi-sheet Excel files.  If there is a better way, I am also open to suggestions for that as well.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just checking, because you haven't mentioned it, but does the server have Excel installed on it?

Comment: Yeppers.  Well... come to think of it, I have O365 installed... Perhaps hard install of Excel? ...  Hmmm....

Comment: You require Excel to be installed to use the COM object. I'd look at using [this module](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel) on your server rather than installing Excel.

Comment: Actually, SQL Server is aware of Excel as the SSIS job that processes this same data functions correctly. Unless I am mis-interpreting how they function together.

Comment: Does this line of code work on the SQL Server in a PowerShell console `$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application`?

Comment: I already have that module installed... `7.1.0      ImportExcel                         PSGallery            PowerShell module to import/export Excel spreads`

Comment: Yes.  works fine in powershell, powershell as admin, and in an ISE console.

Comment: I don't know why you need the COM object if you are using that module. It's specifically made for people who do not have Excel installed or the COM module available.

Comment: I'll go back and check to see if I need to change the code.  I was using multiple examples, so it may just need me to adjust the thought process.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I would stick to using commands from the module exclusively if they can achieve what you need. Good luck.

Comment: I agree.  Got the initial build to work and now going for the real task.  Thanks for the heads up.  I'll try and stick to single threaded examples instead of the "whatever I can find" model.